# Can dojo bind user-defined event?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, dojo, jquery-events

I use the dojo 1.7 version, I want to bind user-defined event, in jQuery I can do like this:

```
$(window).bind("pushMessage",function(){});
```

then trigger the event like this:

```
$(window).trigger("pushMessage",{});
```

Can dojo get the same result like above? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can via [`dojo/on`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/on):

```
on(window, "pushMessage", function(event) {});

on.emit(window, "pushMessage", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/MQThM/

There is also [`dojo/Evented`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/Evented) which provides a class that can be used as a base class or mixin for JavaScript classes that emit their own events. An example from documentation:

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/Evented"
], function(
    declare,
    Evented
) {

    var MyComponent = declare([Evented], {
        startup: function() {
            this.emit("ready", {});
        }            
    });

    var component = new MyComponent();
    component.on("ready", function() {
        console.log("Component is ready.");        
    });

    component.startup();

});​
```

Also at jsFiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/ZhG58/

Comment: Thanks phusick,your method is correct!I get my expected result!Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to publish/subscribe global events, you may find [dojo/topic](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/topic.html) helpful.